# A key cannot be configured on 'Foo' because it is a derived type. The key must be configured on the root type 'ApplicationUser'

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I got this error on db migratios:

> A key cannot be configured on 'Foo' because it is a derived type. The
> key must be configured on the root type 'ApplicationUser'. If you did
> not intend for 'ApplicationUser' to be included in the model, ensure
> that it is not referenced by a DbSet property on your context,
> referenced in a configuration call to ModelBuilder, or referenced from
> a navigation on a type that is included in the model.

And from the search it seems that it is quite common as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66621596/a-key-cannot-be-configured-on-applicationuser-because-it-is-a-derived-type-th), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54718843/entity-framework-cannot-be-configured-on-xxx-class-because-it-is-a-derived-ty) and in other questiosn as well.

I am trying to inherit from ApplicationUser model, but I get the error above. Can anyone explain why is this happening, and what could be a solution?

```cs
namespace Domain.Entities
{
    public partial class Foo : ApplicationUser, IAuditTrial
    {
        [Key]
        public string FooId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("UserId")]
        public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```cs
namespace Domain.Identity
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser, IHasDomainEvent, IAuditTrial
    {
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public bool IsLive { get; set; }
        public string RefreshToken { get; set; }
        public DateTime RefreshTokenExpiryTime { get; set; }
        // Navigation properties
        public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUserClaim> Claims { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUserLogin> Logins { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUserToken> Tokens { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Foo Entity Configurations:

```cs
    public class FooConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Foo>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Foo> builder)
        {
            // builder.Ignore(e => e.DomainEvents);
            builder.HasKey(t => t.Id);
            builder.Property<int>("Id").HasMaxLength(16)
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

            builder.HasOne(d => d.User)
                 .WithMany(p => p.Foos)
                 .HasForeignKey(t => t.FooId)
                 .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        }
    }
```

ApplicationUser Configurations:

```cs
        public class ApplicationUserConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ApplicationUser> builder)
        {
            //....
            builder.HasMany(e => e.Foos)
                         .WithOne(e => e.User)
                         .HasForeignKey(uc => uc.FooId)
                         .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

           // ... more configs
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ApplicationUser has a primary key already. As Foo derives from ApplicationUser, it must also have this key. And you cannot have two primary keys for an entity, so decorating FooId with [Key] is causing this issue.

Most likely, Foo should not inherit from ApplicationUser, but just have it as a related entity, but that depends on your intent.

Comment: How can I add it as related entity? I want to create different kind of users, based on ApplicationUser?

Comment: You've already done so by having an ApplicationUser property in your Foo class with "UserId" as the foreign key. If Foo is supposed to be a kind of user, it's primary key should still be the UserId inherited from ApplicationUser, and you should remove the [key] attribute from FooId (or possibly remove FooId completely)

Comment: I still get the same error, is there any other place where I should look for the error, maybe db  context or some other place?

Comment: Ah, you will also need to remove the `builder.HasKey(t => t.Id);` from the Foo EntityTypeConfiguration